# combine parallel and pbdMPI packages

Tags: r, mpi

I  use mpirun to execute an R script with MPI parallelization, using the snowfall package.

I set upt the parallelization by
'''

> sfInit(parallel = TRUE)
> '''
> then I have
> *** An error occurred in MPI_Init
> *** on a NULL communicator
> *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
> ***    and potentially your MPI job)
> [red075.cluster.local:190363] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!

when I launch the script with mpirun and add '''sfInit(parallel = TRUE, type = "MPI")''  in the script, I have the error
Error in makeMPIcluster(.sfOption$nodes, outfile = tmp, homogenous = TRUE,  :
MPI cluster of size 39 already running
Error in sfInit(parallel = TRUE, type = "MPI") :
Starting of snow cluster failed! Error in makeMPIcluster(.sfOption$nodes, outfile = tmp, homogenous = TRUE,  :
MPI cluster of size 39 already running
Error in makeMPIcluster(.sfOption$nodes, outfile = tmp, homogenous = TRUE,  :
MPI cluster of size 39 already running
Execution halted

I tried not to use sfInit but the code will be run in a sequential mode instead of parallel.
'''

> sfSource("CopulaFunctions.R")
> '''
> then I have :
> Calling a snowfall function without calling 'sfInit' first or after sfStop().
> 'sfInit()' is called now.
> snowfall 1.84-6.3 initialized: sequential execution, one CPU.

===== edit:  adding SLURM job script
In R code  I use

```
library(snowfall)    
sfSetMaxCPUs( number = 40 )
sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 40, type = "MPI")  ...etc
```

yes  I submitted Slurm jobs on MPI cluster

```
 #!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --nodes=1                # Number of nodes requested
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=40     # Tasks per node
#SBATCH --time=20:00:00
 
module load openmpi/4.1.4/intel
module load gsl/2.7
module load R
 
 
 
# Run R script in batch mode
mpirun  -n 40 /local/software/R/4.2.1/build-gcc/lib64/R/library/snow/RMPISNOW CMD BATCH test_rmpi.R outputrmpi.out
```

======= Updata: This is the code after fixing the error and being able to run the code successfully.

```
library(xts)
library(rugarch)
library(mvtnorm)
library(copula)
library(pbdMPI)
library(parallel)
cores <- 40

# here reading the data  (reading or defining n, N, lag, q, V,ll)

# DAX 30
DAX.data  <- read.csv("GDAXI.csv", header=TRUE)  # make sure csv-file is in working directory!
DAX       <- rev(DAX.data$Close)                        # DAX closing prices from 2000-01-01 to 2020-12-31
Datum.DAX <- rev(DAX.data$Date)[-1]                     # read in dates and ...
Datum.DAX <- as.Date(Datum.DAX, "%m/%d/%y")             # ... convert dates.
lr.DAX    <- diff( log(DAX) )                           # Investigate losses
lr.DAX    <- xts(x = lr.DAX,  order.by = Datum.DAX)     # create xts-object for easier manipulation

# GSPC
GSPC.data  <- read.csv("GSPC.csv", header=TRUE)  # make sure csv-file is in working directory!
GSPC       <- rev(GSPC.data$Close)                      # GSPC closing prices from 2000-01-01 to 2020-12-31
Datum.GSPC <- rev(GSPC.data$Date)[-1]                   # read in dates and ...
Datum.GSPC <- as.Date(Datum.GSPC, "%m/%d/%y")           # ... convert dates.
lr.GSPC    <- diff( log(GSPC) )                         # Investigate losses
lr.GSPC    <- xts(x = lr.GSPC,  order.by = Datum.GSPC)  # create xts-object for easier manipulation

# merge both DAX and GSPC
V.lr    <- merge.xts(lr.DAX, lr.GSPC, all=FALSE)        # merged log-returns and ...
V.ll    <- -V.lr                                        # ... log-losses
Datum   <- index(V.lr)                                  # save dates for later use
N       <- nrow(V.lr)                                   # total length of time series (includes some observations after 2019)
n       <- 1000                                         # length of rolling window


# ===========================================================
# 2. Rolling-window analysis of CoVaR and VaR forecasts
# ===========================================================


lag    <- 1     # use estimated model to forecast (lag)-steps-ahead, then re-estimate (i.e., we use daily re-estimates)
p      <- 0.95   # equals \alpha in paper
q      <- 0.95 



source("CopulaFunctions.R")
source("MLEstimation.R")
source("RMApplication.R")

wrapper <- function(i, n, lag, p, q, spec, V.ll){
  (set.seed(12345 + i) ) # set rng stream for ith loop item    
  # 1. Estimate rolling-window parameters
  R   <- t(coredata(V.ll[(i-n+1) : (i+lag), ]))
  Est <- GARCH.est(R, spec, lag, v=10)
 if (is.logical(Est) && !Est) {
    print("Estimation failed, skipping...")
    return(NA)
  }        # if estimators did not converge
  
  # 2. Produce rolling window CoVaR forecasts
  R <- t(coredata( V.ll[(i+1) : (i+lag), ] ))
  CoVaR.forecasts.t <- CoVaR.t.forecast(R, Est$U, Est$eps, Est$Fn.1, Est$Fn.2, Est$outp1, Est$outp2, Est$GAS.t, lag, p, q)

  CoVaR.forecasts.Gauss <- CoVaR.Gauss.forecast( R, Est$U, Est$eps, Est$Fn.1, Est$Fn.2, Est$outp1, Est$outp2, Est$GAS.Gauss, lag, p, q)
  
  return( list(CoVaR.forecasts.t     = CoVaR.forecasts.t,
               CoVaR.forecasts.Gauss = CoVaR.forecasts.Gauss) )
}




loop <- seq.int(from = n, to = N- 1, by = lag)

# GARCH(1,1)
spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), submodel = "GARCH"),
                  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = TRUE),
                  distribution.model = "norm")          # simple GARCH(1,1) specification
Forecasts.GARCH <- mclapply(loop, wrapper,n =n, lag=lag, p=p, q=q, spec, V.ll=V.ll, mc.cores = cores)

print(Forecasts.GARCH)


# GJR-GARCH(1,1)
spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "gjrGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)),
                mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = TRUE),
                  distribution.model = "norm")          # GJR-GARCH(1,1) specification

Forecasts.GJR  <- mclapply(loop,wrapper,n= n, lag=lag, p=p, q=q, spec, V.ll=V.ll, mc.cores = cores)

print(Forecasts.GJR)

finalize()
```

My only problem now is how to run it in 2 nodes , I have tried to request 2 nodes but unfortunately it calculated each iteration twice.

Any advise how to deal with that. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a small example and give some information of your platform? For example, are you running on a cluster with a Slurm workload manager?

Comment: please see the question after providing the Slurm job

Comment: what if you start only one mpi task?

Comment: Please look at the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77672982/is-this-task-suitable-for-rslurm/77706764#77706764. Parallelization on clusters with MPI is more easily done with SPMD-style programming. The snow package (which snowfall uses) was originally designed for a network of workstations and a manager-workers setup that is not ideal for today's clusters. You might also consider `mclapply()` from the parallel package if only one node is involved. With several nodes, a hybrid of `mclapply()` and MPI (via pbdMPI) works best in my experience.

Comment: please see my comment in your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77672982/is-this-task-suitable-for-rslurm/77706764#77706764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment in the other question, I see that the code you are trying to run is easy to modify for running with a combination of MPI (via **pbdMPI**) and Unix fork (via `parallel::mclapply()`.

The snow package predates MPI and Slurm. Although it has been updated, it is designed for manager-workers programming, which is not how MPI is typically used on today's Linux clusters.

Further, running 40 MPI instances per node will make 40 copies of your data per node. A better approach is to use `parallel::mclapply` within a node and  MPI to scale across nodes.

Try the following for `code.R`

```
library(xts)
library(rugarch)
library(mvtnorm)
library(copula)
library(pbdMPI)
library(parallel)
cores <- 40

# here reading the data  (reading or defining n, N, lag, q, V,ll)

source("CopulaFunctions.R")
source("MLEstimation.R")
source("RMApplication.R")

wrapper <- function(i, loop, n, lag, p, q, spec, V.ll){
  comm.set.stream(i) # set rng stream for ith loop item
  i <- loop[i] # select ith loop item
  
  # 1. Estimate rolling-window parameters
  R   <- t(coredata(V.ll[(i-n+1) : (i+lag), ]))
  Est <- GARCH.est(R, spec, lag, v=10)
  if(is.na(Est)){return(NA)}            # if estimators did not converge
  
  # 2. Produce rolling window CoVaR forecasts
  R <- t(coredata( V.ll[(i+1) : (i+lag), ] ))

  CoVaR.forecasts.t <- CoVaR.t.forecast(R, Est$U, Est$eps, Est$Fn.1, Est$Fn.2, Est$outp1, Est$outp2, Est$GAS.t, lag, p, q)

  CoVaR.forecasts.Gauss <- CoVaR.Gauss.forecast( R, Est$U, Est$eps, Est$Fn.1, Est$Fn.2, Est$outp1, Est$outp2, Est$GAS.Gauss, lag, p, q)
  
  return( list(CoVaR.forecasts.t     = CoVaR.forecasts.t,
               CoVaR.forecasts.Gauss = CoVaR.forecasts.Gauss) )
}

loop    <- seq.int(from = n, to = N-lag, by = lag)    # loop over these
my_vec <- comm.chunk(length(loop), form = "vector", rng = TRUE, seed = 12345)

# GARCH(1,1)
spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), submodel = "GARCH"),
                  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = TRUE),
                  distribution.model = "norm")          # simple GARCH(1,1) specification
Forecasts.GARCH <- mclapply(my_vec, wrapper, loop=loop, n, lag=lag, p=p, q=q, spec, V.ll=V.ll, mc.cores = cores)

saveRDS(Forecasts.GARCH, file = paste0("GARCH", comm.rank(), ".rds"))

# GJR-GARCH(1,1)
spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "gjrGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)),
                  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = TRUE),
                  distribution.model = "norm")          # GJR-GARCH(1,1) specification

Forecasts.GJR  <- mclapply(my_vec, wrapper, loop=loop, n, lag=lag, p=p, q=q, spec, V.ll=V.ll, mc.cores = cores)

saveRDS(Forecasts.GJR, file = paste0("GJR", comm.rank(), ".rds"))

finalize()
```

Submit this to Slurm with this SLURM.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --output=output.job9.log
#SBATCH --error=error.job9.log
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --time=22:30:00

module load openmpi/4.1.4/intel
module load gsl/2.7
module load R/4.2.1
export OMPI_MCA_mpi_warn_on_fork=0

time mpirun --map-by ppr:1:node Rscript code.R
```

This will run two copies of `code.R`, each working on its own part of the loop. It assumes that you have nodes with 40 or more cores. The big advantage of using `mclapply()` is that the input data is in shared memory and not copied. At the same time, you can scale to as many nodes as you like just with the SLURM.sh script - the code.R adapts by splitting `length(loop)` into `my_vec` chunks. Each loop index has its own RNG, so this is reproducible with any split across nodes and cores.

Note that I have removed your print statements as it is best to just return results. Printing from 40 cores running in parallel is not recommended. Also, note that each node saves the results (a list with `length(my_vec)` elements) in a uniquely named `.rds` file. The timing of your run is done with `time` in the shell script.

I did not run this as I don't have your data. Let me know how this runs for you.

*** Added explanation ***

What happens is that the shell script allocates two nodes with Slurm and gives exclusive access to all cores on the nodes. OpenMPI's `mpirun` runs 2 copies of the Rscript, one on each node, as specified by the `--map-by` argument. These are sometimes referred to as "tasks." There is overlap in terms of who controls what between Slurm and OpenMPI and the same thing can be specified in more than one way but the defaults can vary among HPC clusters, generating confusion for users. The use of 40 cores here is managed by `mclapply()` via the Unix fork (see [What is the purpose of fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985051/what-is-the-purpose-of-fork)) on its exclusively available cores.

There is a difference between forked processes and threads, which can be seen by monitoring your run with `top -u <your_user_id>`. Slurm typically allows `ssh` logins to the compute nodes where your job is running and here you can use `top` to monitor a node. Forking 40 R processes appears as 40 separate R jobs running, whereas using 40 threads appears as one R job consuming up to 4000% CPU. But in both cases, all or most of the memory space is shared and not duplicated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I submitted the job and it's still running but the error file has this warning : 
A process has executed an operation involving a call to the
"fork()" system call to create a child process.  Open MPI is currently
operating in a condition that could result in memory corruption or
other system errors; your job may hang, crash, or produce silent
data corruption.  The use of fork() (or system() or other calls that
create child processes) is strongly discouraged.
The warning has 4 more lines but I can not provide it here it's longer than the limit

Comment: update on the running code:  after 5 hours of running the job, it failed: 
 the error file  : 
in addition to the above warning we have  
Warning message:
In mclapply(my_vec, wrapper, loop = loop, n, lag = lag, p = p, q = q,  :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
Error in Forecasts.GARCH[[i]]$CoVaR.forecasts.t : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Execution halted
Error in Forecasts.GARCH[[i]]$CoVaR.forecasts.t : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Execution halted

Comment: please note the the Job Output file :
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] "i = "
[1] 1
[1] "i = "
[1] 1

Comment: I have added `export OMPI_MCA_mpi_warn_on_fork=0` to remove the fork warning. It is not a problem to use the Unix fork with MPI, when MPI calls are not made inside any forked process as is the case here. The `$operator is invalid for atomic vectors` happens because `mclapply()` returned NULL for some of the forked processes. To debug the `mclapply()` code, I would severely reduce the length of your `loop`, set `cores <- 1`, and check if the `wrapper()` function is working as expected. In this case, you can run `code.R` interactively as it becomes a serial code.

Comment: The Job Output file looks like you may have kept some of the print() statements? Your output should be the `.rds` files only, which you can load into an interactive R session and examine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I followed your advise and fixed the error however I am not able to run the code in two nodes, as it duplicates the calculation. I added the fixed code in the question

Comment: It is duplicated because you are not splitting the work with `my_vec <- comm.chunk(....)`, which returns a different `my_vec` to each node instance. Note that in my code `loop` is replicated on each node but a different portion of it, indexed by `my_vec`, is used by each node. I also use this index to manage different non-overlapping reproducible random number streams via `comm.set.stream()`. Another reason for introducing `my_vec` is that `loop` is non-contiguous so it can not manage the RNG directly.

Comment: I have one question : when I submitted the job using the SLURM.sh description provided by you, the output file contains 

Partition       : batch
Num hosts       : 2
Num cores       : 80
Num of tasks    : 2
why number of task = 2 ? is this will make the process slower ? or this is normal

Comment: It is normal. I have added some explanation in my answer.